# How to compare date with timestamp field type in firebase firestore database flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the records matching the date. However, I'm unable to do so because the field type in firebase is timestamp. I only want the records exactly matching that specified date. Please let me know if this is possible. Thank you.

```
DateTime tsdate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(mydate*1000);
      
print(DateTime(tsdate.year, tsdate.month, tsdate.day));
//the date is 2022-04-06 00:00:00.000



 FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('cars')
                  .where('datecreated',

                  isEqualTo: DateTime(tsdate.year, tsdate.month, tsdate.day)),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query items, that have been created at a specific date, try this:

```dart
final startTime = DateTime(2022,4,5);
final endTime = DateTime(2022,4,6);
FirebaseForestore.instance.
                 .collection('cars')
                 .where('datecreated', isGreaterOrEqualTo:  startTime)
                 .where('datecreated', isLessOrEqualTo : endTime)
```

If you wanted to use the `isEqualTo` operator you'd need to specify the millisecond that you want to query.

Comment: I have grouped the records according to date dynamically, so I won't be able to specify the end date of a group

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the date from the app with the timestamp value on Firebase, it's easy to do so in this way.

As in your case:

```dart
DateTime tsdate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(mydate*1000);

print(DateTime(tsdate.year, tsdate.month, tsdate.day));
//the date is 2022-04-06 00:00:00.000

FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('cars')
                  .where('datecreated',
                  isEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime(tsdate.year, tsdate.month, tsdate.day)),
```

The same process applies to other comparison options available on `.where()` while writing a Firebase query.